# Customize Apache Spark implementation of TF-IDF

Tags: apache-spark, tf-idf

In one hand I want to use spark capability to compute TF-IDF for a collection of documents, on the other hand, the typical definition of TF-IDF (that Spark implementation is based on that) is not fit in my case. I want the TF to be term frequency among all documents, but in the typical TF-IDF, it's for each pair of (word, document). The IDF definition is the same as the typical definition.

I implemented my customized TF-IDF using Spark RDDs, but I was wondering if there any way to customize the source of the Spark TF-IDF so that I can use the capability of that, like Hashing.

Actually, I need something like :

```
public static class newHashingTF implements Something<String>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple to implement different hashing strategies, as you can see by the simplicity of `HashingTF`:

- (modern) [Dataset version](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/HashingTF.scala)
- (old) [RDD version](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/HashingTF.scala)

This [talk and its slides](https://databricks.com/session/extending-spark-machine-learning-adding-your-own-algorithms-and-tools) can help and there are many others online.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not familiar with Scala. Is there any Java example of that?

Comment: I don't know of any. BTW, you don't need to be a Scala guru to create an extension as you can use the structure from `HashingTF` and then just call your Java code at the right place. This should help: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html